# PyGTK Notebook get_current_page() not working

Tags: python, gtk

I am using a gtk.Notebook widget for the first time and trying to get my application to "remember" the page it was turned to when I quit. However, the get_current_page method doesn't appear to be working. This code:

```
self.notebook = gtk.Notebook()
self.singleFilePane = gtk.Label("Single File")
self.notebook.append_page(self.singleFilePane, gtk.Label("Single File"))
self.multiFilePane = gtk.Label("Multiple Files")
self.notebook.append_page(self.multiFilePane, gtk.Label("Multiple Files"))
print self.notebook.get_n_pages(), self.notebook.get_current_page()
```

Prints the following output:

```
2 -1
```

The -1 result from notebook.get_current_page is supposed to mean the Notebook has no pages, but obviously it does because I just added them, and get_n_pages agrees. I can't see what, if anything, I could be doing wrong here; is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gtk.Notebook has not been shown so the current page has not been set yet. Following code shows the notebook by adding it to toplevel window.

```
self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
self.notebook = gtk.Notebook()
self.singleFilePane = gtk.Label("Single File")
self.notebook.append_page(self.singleFilePane, gtk.Label("Single File"))
self.multiFilePane = gtk.Label("Multiple Files")
self.notebook.append_page(self.multiFilePane, gtk.Label("Multiple Files"))
self.window.add(self.notebook)
self.window.show_all()
print self.notebook.get_n_pages(), self.notebook.get_current_page()
```

This prints

```
2 0
```